# Return to main method from another method in another class

Tags: c#

My main method allows the user to choose to go into a method in class `Function`. Methods within `Function` sometimes lead to other methods also within `Function`, this causes me to be unable to use the `return;` function to simply go back to the main method. I tried using `MainClass.Main(null)` to return but the problem with this is that it resets stored data in my arrays and lists. How could I return to main?

Sample code for `Main`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c;
        Function func = new Function();
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Choose: ");
            c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    func.Register();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    func.Login();
                    break;
                    }
        }while (c != 0);
    }
```

Sample code for `Function`:

```
public void LoggedIn(string n)
    {
        int c;
        name = n;
        Console.WriteLine("User {0} logged in!", name());
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter choice: ");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    case1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    case2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    case3();
                    break;
            }
        } while (c != 0);
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("USER LOGGED OUT.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        //return to main menu
    }
```

Comment: If you can't control your logic flow, re-think your logic.  When you want to return from a method, return from it.  That's true for any method, regardless of where it is in your logic flow.  It's not clear to me specifically what the problem is here, it just sounds like you've tried to implement something but have become confused about the logic you want to write.

Comment: @MongZhu: Using exceptions for logic flow control is a famously bad idea.

Comment: @David I know, it sounds like he would like ab abort option. How would you realize that in this context?

Comment: @MongZhu: I'd stop focusing on trying to return from nested methods and take a step back to more simply define the actual logic one is trying to implement.  Currently the OP has dug himself into a hole.  Rather than step out of the hole, he's trying to get out by digging deeper.  Instead, he should accept the possibility that he has done something wrong and re-think his approach.

Comment: @David yup! Sounds like I have to since it's the simplest way to go about it anyway.

Comment: @David very good argument!

Comment: @David quick update, since I'm a beginner I couldn't really understand the given answer, but after fixing my logic, I can use `return;` to go back to main now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there are two situations when you need to return to `Main`:

- User requested returning to `Main`, or
- A recoverable error state has been reached, requiring a return to `Main`

In the first case you need to build a logic for returning to `Main` into your code: each method needs to inform its caller that a return to `Main` has been requested, and the caller must obey and return.

For example, if `case1`, `case2`, or `case3` could decide that a return to `Main` must be performed, make them return `bool`, and check its value inside `Login`, like this:

```
bool case1() {...}
bool case2() {...}
bool case3() {...}
...
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        if (case1()) return;
        break;
    case 2:
        if (case2()) return;
        break;
    case 3:
        if (case3()) return;
        break;
}
```

In the second scenario (recoverable error) throw an exception from a method, catch it in the `Main`, do the cleanup, and continue execution.